# mongoose connection error always

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

whenerver i try to connect mongodb using mongoose following error occurred.

```
  { db: { native_parser: true },
   server: { poolSize: 5 },
    user: '',
    pass: '' }
```

> +++++++++++++++++++++++ SERVER STARTED +++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Server running at:http://127.0.0.1:5000 DB Error jobs: { [MongoError:
>   auth failed] name: 'MongoError', message: 'auth failed', ok: 0,
>   errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 } var option = { db: { native_parser:
>   true }, server: { poolSize: 5 }, user:db.username, pass:db.password, }
>
> mongoose.connect(option, option, function(err) {if (err) { process.exit(1); } else { console.log('MongoDB Connected', mongoUrl);
>   } })

Comment: Assuming that you're running mongodb locally, try checking mongodb logs for which user its trying to authenticate against. This will give you clear picture whats being passed through the connection string. If that looks same as what you intended to pass, then you may need to do console.log with your auth details